# Code coverage with GCOV can't produce .gcda file

Tags: unit-testing, code-coverage, gcov

I want to get code coverage with GCOV, I set build setting by  http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa2007/qa1514.html

- add "-lgcov" to "Other Linker Flags"
- check "Instrument Program Flow"
- check "Generate Test Coverage Files"

but I can't produce the .gcda file, could anyone help?

Comment: Upvoted as I'm having the same issue. SDK 4.2.1, XCode 3.2.5

Comment: I'm not sure how xcode works, but you do know that compiling only produces .gcno files - you have to run the application and make it quit to produce .gcda files and then you have to run gcov, possibly several times, to produce .gcov files.

Comment: This answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5140459/391668 fixes this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The simulator has to close before the gcda files get generated. So, when I run GHUnit I have to close this app first. There's also a setting in the plist to kill the app when it closes, rather than have it sit there ready to restart.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Xcode 4.3.2. Setting "Generate Profiling Code" to YES caused that after testing gcda files are generated.