# Code coverage not showing results using Xcode + gcov

Tags: objective-c, xcode, code-coverage

I have been trying to get the Code coverage working for iPhone simulator and always get a 0% coverage. Below are the configuration details and the steps that I have tried.

**Configuration**

Xcode 3.2.5/iOS 4.1 and iOS 4.2/Mac 10.6/GCC 4.2
Application
UICatalog

**References**

http://www.cubiclemuses.com/cm/articles/2009/05/14/coverstory-on-the-iphone/

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa2007/qa1514.html

**Steps**

- Enable “Generate Test Coverage Files”
- Enable “Instrument Program Flow”
- Add “`-lgcov`” to “Other Linker Flags”
- `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` flag in Info.plist is set to true

**Result**

I have the .gcda files generated but the coverage always show 0%.

**Settings tried**

1. Changing GCC to 4.0 and 4.2. When I try to change the GCC to 4.0 I get 26 build errors.
2. Set environment variables

   ```
   (const char *prefix = "GCOV_PREFIX";
   const char *prefixValue = [[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]; // This gets the filepath to the app's Documents directory
   const char *prefixStrip = "GCOV_PREFIX_STRIP";
   const char *prefixStripValue = "1";
   setenv(prefix, prefixValue, 1); // This sets an environment variable which tells gcov where to put the .gcda files.
   setenv(prefixStrip, prefixStripValue, 1); // This tells gcov to strip the default prefix, and use the filepath that we just declared.)
   ```
3. GCC Optimization set to None (-O0) and unchecked the precompiled prefix header file flag.

Comment: can we do code coverage for iphone device?(i.e. not for simulator)

Answer (score 19):

Thanks for all the info on stackoverfow and [CubicleMuses](http://www.cubiclemuses.com/cm/articles/2009/05/14/coverstory-on-the-iphone/)

I have code coverage working for both simulator and device! Here are the steps and configuration that worked for me:

Configuration : Xcode 4 !

**XCode project settings**

*Build Settings*

- Other Linker Flags: add "-lgcov"
- GCC_GENERATE_TEST_COVERAGE_FILES: Set
  to YES
- GCC_INSTRUMENT_PROGRAM_FLOW_ARCS: Set
  to YES
- C/C++ Compiler Version: GCC
  4.2 (if you are on XCode 4) iOS deployment target: 4.2
- Precompile prefix header: NO

*Info.plist*

- Set UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend flag
  in your Info.plist to YES

Above steps are same for Simulator and Device however, we have some extra work to make it work on Device.

**Main.m**: Copy paste the below code to main.m

```
const char *prefix = "GCOV_PREFIX";
const char *prefixValue = [[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]; // This gets the filepath to the app's Documents directory
const char *prefixStrip = "GCOV_PREFIX_STRIP";
const char *prefixStripValue = "1";
setenv(prefix, prefixValue, 1); // This sets an environment variable which tells gcov where to put the .gcda files.
setenv(prefixStrip, prefixStripValue, 1); // This tells gcov to strip the default prefix, and use the filepath that we just declared.
```

Note: Make sure the above code is before:

```
NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
[pool release];    
return retVal;
```

Why we set the above coverage variables?

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Cross_002dprofiling.html

How to get the .gcda files?

Use the Organizer in Xcode to download app's package from the device to get the .gcda files out of the Documents directory.

**Note:** I could not get the code coverage using Xcode 3.2.5 with the same settings. But Xcode 4 was a cake-walk :-)

Comment: Wow after 2 weeks of headache i read your post and got it to work in about 5 minutes :) you are my hero, thanks

Comment: Even after following all the steps mentioned, I am not able to generate code coverage as .gcda files are not getting generated. I am setting up code coverage for my Mac app. Anyone has similar problem?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Sangavi since your answer helped me.

Now the but:
I followed your descripition step by step and than I had the problem that no gcda-files were created (only gcdo-files).

After that I removed your (above) prefix-code which I copied in the main.m and everything worked suddenly. Bet the gcov-path was not created correctly or something.

Just posting this if anyone runs into the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I just figured out after hours of frustration that enabling distributed builds in Xcode 3.2.6 will work around the need to disable your prefix header.

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem that no files were created at all.
This was in Xcode 4.1 on Lion.

I changed the compiler from `System Default (GCC 4.2)` to `GCC 4.2`.
So NOT use the system default.

Seems like a bug in Xcode, but it solved the problem for me.
When i changed back the preference the problem returned.