# How do I get code coverage for tests and build for iPhone in Xcode 4?

Tags: iphone, unit-testing, xcode4, code-coverage, llvm

I have a couple of projects with unit tests where I want to measure coverage. So I follow the instructions detailed in the [How-to for CoverStory](http://code.google.com/p/coverstory/wiki/UsingCoverstory) and elsewhere on the web.

I add `-fprofile-arcs` and `-ftest-coverage` to my test target and the target under test and link to `/Developer/usr/lib/libprofile_rt.dylib` as specified.

And it works! When I run the tests scheme under the iPhone simulator, I get my code coverage, my tests and app build and run.

But then, when I go back to the Run scheme on actual iPhone hardware, I get a link error for libprofile_rt.dylib. Specifically, I get

> ld: library not found for -lprofile_rt

What I suspect here is that libprofile_rt is actually a library for Mac hardware and the iPhone obviously can't link to a binary built for Mac, in general.

My question is **How do run on iPhone hardware *and* get my code coverage?**

I suspect I can do this with a copy of my Debug target that is only ever used for testing, but that has the additional trouble of maintaining yet another target. Is there any other way to get this working? Am I doing something silly?

Comment: There is iOS version of this lib at /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/lib/libprofile_rt.dylib Maybe you should try linking new target with this one

Comment: Good find, but that gives me different errors: I get a warning saying "ignoring file /Developer/.../libprofile_rt.dylib, missing required architecture armv7 in file." Because the linker ignores that file, then I get undefined symbol errors. So then I went to Architectures in Build Settings for my target and hardcoded armv7 and get the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

might a little bit late but actually you can. it is explained in [this presentation](http://lanyrd.com/2012/lidg44/sytpc/), slides 32 to 34.

took me a fair amount of time to find this hidden gem. hope this might help future visitor of this page.

Comment: Great find! Looks like you have to copy the files manually. That sucks, but Apple is the only one able to fix that.

Comment: yes, manually copying the file is the only way to get those gcda files out. that is really a shame as our CI is ready to roar with those files and that our project can't run in the simulator. maybe with Xcode 5 ;)

Answer (score 0):

Possible answer to this problem is here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/5140459

The trick is to get the *.gcda files out of the App's Documents directory via Xcode organizer, since they will, of course, be generated on device.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: **you can't run on your device AND get coverage at the same time.** The only way to get coverage is on the simulator: make a copy of your debug target, setup coverage and what not on that target and run that target, with your tests, in the simulator.

I go through all the details in an answer to this question on stackoverflow: [Code coverage on iOS Using Xcode 4.2 on Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8459330/code-coverage-on-ios-using-xcode-4-2-on-lion/8476639#8476639)