# How to get gcno files when build to physical device

Tags: ios, code-coverage, gcov

Recently, I'm working on ios code coverage. following this link:

[Code coverage not showing results using Xcode + gcov](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101014/code-coverage-not-showing-results-using-xcode-gcov)

I have been able to get it when run on **simulator**, the gcno and gcda files are together with build objects. But to **real device**, it's different, I got gcda files in device, but whether in my mac or my device, I cannot find the **gcno** files, can anyone help me? thanks very much.

Comment: How did you do you get gcda files in device??

Comment: @gurooj, It's been a long time since my previous work, I remember gcda files was generated after you do some manipulations on your app, and generated under app's folder, I mean device. like /Applications/yourApp/...