# Why does my code coverage is zero for UITesting in XCode 7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode7, code-coverage, ui-testing

I have enabled code coverage and everything else in my project.
When I tested my app on a simulator, The test passed.

But when I went to check the report, it says that none of my classes and methods are executed? Everything in zero and all my classes and methods have been given he red colours.

Why can't I see any code coverage for my test?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Code coverage not showing results using Xcode + gcov](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101014/code-coverage-not-showing-results-using-xcode-gcov)

Comment: @Cristik This can hardly be a duplicate of a question asked 2011. Xcode has so much changed since then. Even if the reason was the same, the description how to fix it can't be the same anymore.

Comment: Code Coverage works for me in Xcode 7.1.1. Can you make a small test project and load it to somewhere (github for example) where I can download it an check if it works in my Xcode?

Comment: I am sorry. I am not allowed to that - it is a university assignment.
Although I think since I was running the tests method by method, I was not able to achieve code coverage (by clicking that small play button in front of the test method). Running the tests from Product > Test measures code coverage. Strange! :)